# id (value: ) is not of the type Positive (WordPress)

Tags: civievent

using WP 5.4.2 - PHP 7.2 - CiviCRM 5.28

1/ I previously hab issue with CiviCRM Events's permalink: so  activate "Classic Editor" WordPress plugin to allows a link in a post to publish the Events's form

2/ I migrated the website to a new host + activate SSL + Upgrade CiviCRM to the last Release

First issue: the c**onfirmation step of the booking event was no more display**  and there was no registration= looking for the rrot cause I find that CMS integration was not correct so I added **civicrm/** at the end of https://cycloclubbreuillet.fr/

So I get the Second issue : **DB Error : constraint violation**
I read some post hier and chech the wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php and the login information

So I created a new event and now the issue is:  **id (value: ) is not of the type Positive**
See below the debug information:

[image]

in line 90 of he file Request.php i FOUND THIS/
$value = CRM_Utils_Type::validate($value, $type, $abort, $name);

hope some can help, I could(not find the root cause

Comment: can you check the CMS integration in Civi if its set or not?

Comment: Yes it is set with civicrm/          But I am not sure if "/" at ther end is usefull

Comment: nope, and do you have /civicrm page setup?

Comment: Tkank you = I just remove the "/" and the previous errors disappear ----- but I have a new one = DB Error: already exists (I guess I made a lot of testing and it did not remove everything in the DB) ----- the file exist at : /domains/cycloclubbreuillet.fr/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/setup/civicrm-setup-autoload.php      and it says it was provided by previous build .... nothing else

Comment: Can you check civicrm logs /uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

Comment: threr is 35 line like this: #0 wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(205): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(998): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: already exists", -5, 16, (Array:2), "UPDATE  `civicrm_contact`  SET `contact_type` = 'Individual' , `external_iden...")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112212/discussion-between-pradeep-nayak-and-rv91530).